# Jar dependend on classes in war project

Tags: java, maven-2

Suppose I have a war and jar projects defined in maven.

The Jar project is dependent on the War project

I have managed to get this working in package mode by adding

In the war project `<attachClasses>` to true in the war plugin.

And making a dependency to

```
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>oneway-delegator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <classifier>classses</classifier>
```

in the jar pom.

But when running only compile the classes jar is not created and everything fails.

Any ideas folks ??

Comment: I fail to understand your question. Do your war project depend on your jar project or the other way around? If your war project depends on a jar projecct, it should be very straight forward, and the dependency declaration looks good except for the classifier element. It shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Well , i would not be asking this if the war depends on the jar , its the jar depending on the war ( second line in the question )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> But when running only compile the classes jar is not created and everything fails.

You can indeed configure the maven-war-plugin to package/deploy the classes and resources included in your webapp as an "attached" JAR artifact with a classifier with the following configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>X.Y</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But this artifact is created during the `package` phase so don't expect it to be there if you run `compile` only.

Note that this configuration option has been introduced for a very particular use case, the skinny war use case. If you need to re-use this JAR in another project the recommended approach is in general to move the classes to a separate module that builds a JAR, and then declare a dependency on that JAR from your webapp as well as from any other projects that need it.

Answer (score 7):

Don't do this.

That is not an acceptable dependency to make a jar (plain java code) dependent on a war (Java EE specific application package).  If you have code in your war that you are dependent on, then that code should be in it's own jar and then both the web app and the jar project would have a common dependency on it.

Comment: Good advice.  "When in doubt, create another module", when it comes to maven.

Comment: Its a common case when you have a war and a second maven module containing some integration tests of the first webapp. In this case, being able to use the webapp classes and dependencies would be extremely useful.